# Need Check on Proof with Chebychev's Inequality: Statistical Theory

Tags: statistical-inference

So I have a problem with my homework, and I just need to see if my proof and thinking are correct.
 The problem I have is this:
 Show that the sample variance $s^2$ is a consistent estimator for the variance of X, $\sigma^2$.
 I had to manipulate the $\sigma^2$ shortcut formula to get $s^2=\sigma^2\frac{n}{n-1}$.

However, my professor gave us a hint to use the theorem of consistent estimators for moments of X.

This theorem goes: Let X be a random variable with $k^{th}$ moment $\mathrm{E}[X^k]$ unknown. Then $\frac{\sum_iX_i^k}{n}$ is a consistent estimator for $\mathrm{E}[X^k]$.

So I am thinking that when I get to my proof where I have $\frac{n}{n-1}(\mathrm{E}[X^2]-\mathrm{E}[X]^2)$, is where I can say that by this theorem that since $\mathrm{E}[X^2]$ and $\mathrm{E}[X]$ are consistent estimators for $\mathrm{E}[X^k]$ moment, that $s^2$ is a consistent estimator for $\sigma^2$.

Could anyone let me know if my thinking is correct on this?
 Sorry for my code not being so clean, this is my first time really programming in LaTeX. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess $s^2$ is the unbiased estimator for the variance $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)$. It is consistent, if it converges in probability to $\sigma^2$, which means that $\lim_{n\to\infty}P(|s^2-\sigma^2|\geq\epsilon)=0$ for any $\epsilon>0$. 
Now you know by your Professor's theorem that the estimator $s_n^2=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-\bar x)$ is consistent, i.e. $\lim_{n\to\infty}P(|s_n^2-\sigma^2|\geq\epsilon)=0$. Using that it shouldn't be too hard to show, that the other limit also goes to zero.

Comment: I understand that it is consistent in that regard, but should I just take the limits of each of the expected values as they go to infinity just to show that this formula converges in probability to 0?